# Golang Keeps File Serve Socket Open After Close

Tags: linux, macos, sockets, go

I created a file server in golang and call the Close() method on the Listener.

When I try to access the Port on a new Web connection it appears the Socket is closed and I am unable to access the website.

How ever if I referesh the page with a connection that has already been established.... the page reloads fine as if the socket was never closed? I am even able to still browse around the file system.

I noticed after 30 or so minutes the socket seems to force close.

Is there something I am missing to force the socket to drop all existing connections to prevent people from accessing the file server?

```
var fileListener net.Listener
host_string = "127.0.0.1:8080"
fileListener, _ = net.Listen("tcp", host_string)
server := &http.Server{Addr: host_string, Handler:     
http.FileServer(http.Dir("/"))}
go func() { server.Serve(fileListener) }()
fileListener.Close()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no way to shut down idle HTTP/1.1 or HTTP2 connections. There is a an open issue at https://golang.org/issue/9478, but no immediate plans for it. Note that once you close your listener, your server will not accept new connections; you're reusing the same connection.

If you want to forcefully close all connections, you would need to do the bookkeeping yourself using the [`http.Server`](https://godoc.org/net/http#Server) `ConnState` to track the TCP connections that are active.

You could also have your handlers set `Connection: close` on each response, but that would make your http server much less efficient if clients ever need to make more than 1 request.

Comment: Would wrapping the handler with a TimeoutHandler help at all? (https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#TimeoutHandler)

Comment: I followed your recommendation of using ConnState. Works perfectly! Thanks!